# Solucionar IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: programación-móvil

```
#llista_nueva.replace('', )

#aqui tenim tot lo important
if(classes < 15):
    copia[atribut].replace(llista_nueva,llista_numeros,inplace = True)
    print('Atribut', atribut , 'sha substituit correctament perque el numero de clases es', classes)
else:
    print('el numero de clases es molt gran i borrem el atribut')
    copia = dataset.drop(categorical_attributes[i], axis=1)
    atributs_borrats +=1
```

Falla el `replace` cuando esto es lo que hay en las variables, ¿por qué falla?.

```
Lista Nueva: ['mar', 'oct', 'aug', 'sep', 'apr', 'jun', 'jul', 'feb', 'jan', 'dec', 'may', 'nov']
Lista numeros [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, ¿podrías dar más información acerca del lenguaje de programación o marco de trabajo y desarrollo que estás usando?

Comment: A primera vista, sin confirmar lenguaje de programación, veo que esta definición difiere de la anterior (le faltan los dos puntos): `Lista numeros [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`, es posible que esté interpretando el interior de los corchetes como índice y no como una enumeración de datos.

Comment: Esto es phyton y no es que sea distinta es porque las he sacado de un print ahora pongo todo el codigo bien